# Rendering updated data in wrapped elements

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm new to d3, and struggling to understand data binding. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cqjkc/) with the code below.

Let's say I have some data that will get updated later. Note that `6` becomes `1`.

```
data1 = [
    { key: 'orig7', val: 7 },
    { key: 'orig3', val: 3 },
    { key: 'orig6', val: 6 }
];
data2 = [
    { key: 'orig7', val: 7 },
    { key: 'orig3', val: 3 },
    { key: 'orig6', val: 1 },
    { key: 'new5', val: 5 }
];
```

Then I render them. My code requires that the data be embedded deeper into the the elememt. Here are two render functions; they differ only in that the first one is simple, without such a wrapping, and the second one creates an inner div around the text.

```
function render1(data) {
    var result = d3.select('#list1').selectAll('.item')
        .data(data, function(d, i) { return d.key });
    result.enter()
        .append('div')
            .classed('item', true)                       // set up a div
    result                                               // set text in the div
        .text(function(d, i) { return '' + d.key + "=" + d.val; });
    result.exit().remove();
    result.sort(function(a, b) { return a.val < b.val ? -1 : 1 });
}

function render2(data) {
    var result = d3.select('#list2').selectAll('.item')
        .data(data, function(d, i) { return d.key });
    result.enter()
        .append('div')
            .classed('item', true)
        .append('div')                                   // set up an *inner* div
    result.selectAll('div')                              // set text in the inner div
        .text(function(d, i) { return '' + d.key + "=" + d.val; });
    result.exit().remove();
    result.sort(function(a, b) { return a.val < b.val ? -1 : 1 });
}
```

Let's render the data with both render functions.

```
render1(data1);
render1(data2);

render2(data1);
render2(data2);
```

The output is as follows:

```
orig6=1
orig3=3
new5=5
orig7=7

orig6=6
orig3=3
new5=5
orig7=7
```

The sort works well, as it operates on the data stored in `.item`.

However, there is a discrepancy in text. If I insert an inner div, it will inherit the datum from the parent, but this datum will not get updated, and remains `6` (whereas I would like it to reflect the updated value `1`, like in the first rendered example).

Where exactly does the inner div get a copy of the data, and how can I force it to be updated when new data gets bound?

EDIT: the title had nothing to do with the question; apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this is actually incredibly trivial. All you have to do is change

```
result.selectAll('div')
```

to

```
result.select('div')
```

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cqjkc/1/). If you use `.select()`, the data bound to the current selection (the "base" for the new selection) is also bound to the newly-selected elements. If you use `.selectAll()`, this isn't the case. That's exactly what you've been seeing.

It may seem counter-intuitive to use `.select()` here, as you're selecting multiple elements. However, keep in mind that the original selection already contains multiple elements and the selector is executed for each of them. That is, for each element in your current selection, exactly one element is selected with `.select()` (which is what you need in this case), and multiple elements with `.selectAll()` (which makes sense for tree-like hierarchies).

Comment: Oh and in your solution the `.datum(d)` is actually redundant -- the `.select()` takes care of that already.

Comment: Oh. Embarassingly simple :) So - just to check my understanding - `selectAll` promotes nodes to groups, changes root, does not copy data; `select` does not change groups or root, but copies data to new nodes?

Comment: There aren't any groups. Making a selection (regardless of whether with `.select()` or `.selectAll()`) always changes the root (that's the point of making the selection). `.selectAll()` does not copy data, `.select()` does.

Answer (score 0):

Solved using this:

```
result.each(function(d, i) {
  d3.select(this).select('div').datum(d);
});
```

but there has to be a better way I am not seeing. Isn't there?